# Is there a way to improve expo-location lib speed?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm currently integrating expo-location into one of my app's components, but I'm encountering an issue where retrieving coordinates is taking an unusually long time. Has anyone faced a similar issue and found a solution? I'm working with Expo version 50.0.11, which I believe is the latest. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When I disable the 'Precise Location' option in the iOS settings for the app, the response time improves significantly, though at the cost of accuracy.